# $3$-player card game probability question

Tags: probability, card-games

Three people, (call them $C$, $D$, and $E$), decide to play a card game for fun. They use an ordinary fair deck of $52$ cards, shuffled well immediately before each hand is drawn, and randomly draw cards from it one a time without replacement, all $3$ using (sharing) the same drawn cards to determine who wins. A win is defined as follows:

$C$ wins if he gets at least one of all $13$ ranks of the cards (regardless of suit as they can be mixed suit or even all the same suit) in a hand.

$D$ wins if he gets either $6$ reds or $5$ blacks in a row (consecutive) for a particular hand. Each new hand starts with $0$ in a row so there is no "carryover" from a previous hand.

$E$ wins if she gets either $3$ Aces or $4$ of any "picture" card ($J$,$Q$, or $K$).

It is possible for ties to occur but the rule is any ties are awarded as a win for $C$, even if $C$ was not even close to winning the hand.

So the question is who has the highest probability of winning?

Comment: So far I have only tried computer simulation.  My math skills are weak.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what that means.  What did you simulate?  What program did you use to run the simulation?  How many times did you run the simulation?  What were the statistics from your simulation?

Comment: I just used a general purpose language to simulate 1 million hands (winners) and it appears the probabilities are very close to equal for all $3$ players.  Each one very close to $33.33$% chance of winning but D appears to be a slight favorite.

Comment: Did you simulate $1$ million hands then throw away the non-winners, or simulate hands until you accumulated $1$ million winning hands?  How many losing hands occurred?  Are simultaneous losing hands for any two of the players counted as a win for $C$?

Comment: There are no nowinning completed hands.  Each hand will eventually have a winner.  Someone will win way before the $52$nd card is drawn.  A hand continues starting with the 1st card until there is a winner (or a tie which is awarded as a win to C).  This win will happen way before the deck has been exhausted (all $52$ cards are drawn).  So either C, D, or E will win "outright" (no ties for that hand), or someone will tie (either $2$ or all $3$ players) and the win then gets awarded to C.